# Creating a custom y-axis that goes 0, 80, 160, 320, 640, ect

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I am wondering if there is a way to make a graph on excel with a y-axis scale based on a function y(n)=2 X y(n-1).

Specifically, I want a y-axis that has values 0, 80, 160, 320, 640, 1280.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Make your chart. Format the Y axis so that the minimum is zero and the major unit is 80. You can leave the maximum and Excel will pick a max that is a multiple of 80 greater than the highest value, or you can specify it yourself.